# show video Tile in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

how can i show video tile(thumbnail) instead of it's name in exoplayer?

this is the code that i already use , and it's result :

```
public class SampleChooserActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_chooser_activity);

    ListView sampleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sample_list);
    final SampleAdapter sampleAdapter = new SampleAdapter(this);

    sampleAdapter.add(new Header("Local Videos"));
    sampleAdapter.addAll((Object[]) Samples.LOCAL_VIDEOS);

    sampleList.setAdapter(sampleAdapter);
    sampleList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object item = sampleAdapter.getItem(position);
        if (item instanceof Samples.Sample) {
          onSampleSelected((Samples.Sample) item);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private void onSampleSelected(Samples.Sample sample) {
    Intent mpdIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class)
        .setData(Uri.parse(sample.uri))
        .putExtra(PlayerActivity.CONTENT_ID_EXTRA, sample.contentId)
        .putExtra(PlayerActivity.CONTENT_TYPE_EXTRA, sample.type)
        .putExtra(PlayerActivity.PROVIDER_EXTRA, sample.provider);
    startActivity(mpdIntent);
  }

  private static class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
      super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = convertView;
      if (view == null) {
        int layoutId = getItemViewType(position) == 1 ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
            : R.layout.sample_chooser_inline_header;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layoutId, null, false);
      }
      Object item = getItem(position);
      String name = null;
      if (item instanceof Samples.Sample) {
        name = ((Samples.Sample) item).name;
      } else if (item instanceof Header) {
        name = ((Header) item).name;
      }
      ((TextView) view).setText(name);
      return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      return (getItem(position) instanceof Samples.Sample) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
      return 2;
    }

  }

  private static class Header {

    public final String name;

    public Header(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

  }

}
```

xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <ListView android:id="@+id/sample_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

as you see in the image above, the video name is shown,but i want to show tile(thumbnail) of video ( a screenshot of video) instead of video name,how can i do this ? 
**Edit** 
i used this code to get Bitmap as thumbnail but bitmap is null :

```
String path = "file:///android_asset/video1.mp4";
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bellow code to create a thumbnail for your video :

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: thanks,the code has syntax problem , where shoud  i use it ?